# Compare time it takes to travel a curve and a line

Tags: geometry, physics

Suppose you have a right triangle ABC with hypotenuse AB, AC is along gravity direction, C is the right angle. c1 is AB, c2 is a smooth and convex curve within the triangle connecting A and B. You don't know anything else about the triangle or curve c2.

If it takes a particle without initial speed time t1 to travel c1, which is AB and time t2 to travel curve c2, can you compare t1 and t2? Suppose there is no friction.

Now please note that this is not a classic problem, so the solution is not Brachistochrone curve. You need to figure out what the problem is asking first.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the right angle at B or C? I am finding it hard to come up with ABC with AB the hypotenuse and AC is vertical.  Should you say the right angled triangle to be ACB?

Comment: Yes, C is the right angle.